# What is the equivalent of jQuery's n-th child method?

Tags: go

I try to program a first google go program. I got this working part:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func TrimSpaceNewlineInString(s string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(` +\n+ +\t+`)
    return re.ReplaceAllString(s, "")
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    c.OnHTML("tr",
        func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
            ch := e.DOM.Children()
            spalte1 := ch.Eq(0)
            spalte2 := ch.Eq(1)

            spalte1.Each(
                func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
                    fmt.Print(TrimSpaceNewlineInString(s.Text()), ":", TrimSpaceNewlineInString(spalte2.Text()))

                })
        })
    c.Visit("https://deweysearchde.pansoft.de/webdeweysearch/executeSearch.html" +
        "?lastScheduleRecord=669.1-669.7&lastTableRecord=&query=" + args[0] + "&_showShortNotations=off&catalogs=DNB&_catalogs=off&catalogs=GBV&_catalogs=off&catalogs=HeBIS&_catalogs=off&catalogs=SUB&_catalogs=off&catalogs=SWB&_catalogs=off&catalogs=FUB&_catalogs=off")
}
```

But I only what to get the 2nd column, if this is in the range form [0-9.-] and if so than I would need the following 3rd column with the DDC Classification of this DOM HTMLElement talbe.
I would like to retrieve following

```
            600;Technik
            660;Chemische Verfahrenstechnik
            669;Metallurgie
            669.1-669.7;Metallurgie einzelner Metalle und deren Legierungen
            669.1;Eisenmetalle
```

Can anyone here help me and tell me how it could be done with colly [Colly doc for go](https://godoc.org/github.com/gocolly/colly#HTMLElement), which is similar to jQuery?

PS: I have tried this way - with children. But the output looks like this. I do not know why.

```
    Notation:Thema :


                        Haupttafeln
                    600:

                                    Technik

            660:

                                    Chemische Verfahrenstechnik

            661:

                                    Industriechemikalien

            661.2-661.6:

                                    Säuren, Basen, Salze

            661.5:

                                    Ammoniumsalze


            Notation:Thema :HilfstafelnT1--0:Hilfstafel 1. StandardschlüsselT2--0:Hilfstafel 2. Geo ...
```

Comment: a different thing came to my mind while reading your question: The Datasource you are using is under CC License with a no-derivative restriction as visible on the footer of the page. You should ask the content holder of the data if you can use the data if your derivate is publicly available.

Comment: @Lars thanks, but I need it only for inhouse - my derivate should not be used public